# Separating name from numbers in text file

Tags: java, arrays, class, arraylist, text

What I am trying to do is read a text file that looks like this:

```
Tom 96 95 94 93 54
```

And separate the names and numbers. I will then be printing the student's name total score (the total of all the numbers) and the average. I have a separate class called Student which holds the classes:

```
private String name;
   private int numOfQuizzesTaken;
   private int totalScore;
   public Student(String name){
       this.name = name;
   }
   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }
   public int getTotalScore() {
       return totalScore;
   }
   public void addQuiz(int score) {
       totalScore = totalScore + score;
       numOfQuizzesTaken++;
   }
   public double getAverageScore(){
       return totalScore/(double)numOfQuizzesTaken;
   }
}
```

I know i need to use an array but i dont know how to seperate the name from the numbers and store those numbers to be used.
I wrote a similar code without a txt file and it looked like this:

```
Scanner nameInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is your name? ");
    String name = nameInput.next();

    Student student = new Student(name);


    student.addQuiz(96);
    student.addQuiz(94);
    student.addQuiz(93);
    student.addQuiz(92);
       System.out.println("Students Name: " + student.getName());
       System.out.println("Total Quiz Scores: " + student.getTotalScore());
       System.out.println("Average Quiz Score: " + student.getAverageScore());
```

Hopefully this gives some understanding of what i am trying to do and would like any help i can get.

Comment: If your text file keeps the format you mentioned you just need to read it line by line and split the lines by " " then you have String array that contains the name and the scores.

Comment: You will have to read the file to string, seperate by " " and parse the number withe `Integer.toInt("95')`

Comment: The format should be the same but difference in the amount of numbers and the length of the name might change. But from what you said that might not affect that @aussie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to read the file into string then split it with " ". from there you will have the first index to be name and the other indexes to be the scores

```
File score = new File("quiz.txt");
Scanner scn = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(score));
String buffer = "";
while (scn.hasNext()) {
      buffer += scn.nextLine() + "\n";
}
String[] content = buffer.trim().split(" ");
String name  = content[0] ;
Student student = new Student(name);
for (int a = 1 ; a < content.length; a++) {
    int scoreval = Integer.parseInt(content[a]);
    student.addQuiz(scoreval);
}
```

Comment: so I am having an issue with the first line score. The txt file is called TextFile. How do i alter score to use that txt file? i really like this and it's what i need

Comment: the `score` is the txt file `File score = new File("quiz.txt");` while the **quiz.txt** is the relative location of the text file ,

Comment: I have fixed that but it still can't find the file. Do I have the text file in the wrong location?

Comment: you definitely had it in the wrong location. First check the absolute path to the file on your PC then use the absolute path in the `File score = new File("absolute/path/to/quiz.txt");` expression if it work then you can start dealing with the relative path. In my example i assume the text file is in your project directory

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a regular expression to separate the numbers from the names. Once you have extracted the string containing numbers,you can split it by spaces(which will return an array of numbers) and create a hash map for storing the data(only if you have unique names), key being the name and the array of quiz score being the value. Hope this helps. :)

You can parse the numbers into integers or float before storing it into hash map. If the name has only alphabets then this regex should do: `([A-Z,a-z])*\x20*(\d.*)`

- Group 1 will match the name.
- Group 2 will give you the string containing the numbers, lets store it in `String quizScoreString`.

  String[] stringScores= quizScoreString.split("\s+");

Answer (score 0):

If the text file will have the following format, you can read an entire line, then split the string by `" "` character. The first element in array will the the name of the student, the rest of the elements will be the scores. Here's an example :

```
String s = fileReader.nextLine();

String[] split = s.split(" ");

Student student = new Student(split[0]);

Arrays.stream(split).skip(1) // skip the first element as it's a name
    .forEach(score -> student.addQuiz(Integer.parseInt(score)));
```

Comment: I keep getting an error at: .forEach(score -> student.addQuiz(Integer.parseInt(score))); compliance error

Comment: What is the version of the JDK you are using?

Comment: 8 I believe I am using eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the input based using " ", store it in array of String or Object as in the below below, this

> "Tom 96 95 94 93 54"

represents the input you read from the user, it should be a variable, I am assuming that you are reading student info (name, etc ...) in one shot

```
    String[] studentInfoArray = "Tom 96 95 94 93 54".split(" ");
    String name = studentInfoArray[0];
    Integer quiz1 = Integer.parseInt(studentInfoArray[1]);
```

Comment: It is just a code sample, you can use a for loop to read the rest of array elements.